# Passing request Parameters from Managed Bean to A jsf page

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2

I am new to JSF 2.0. I am stuck at the following problem. I have a page from which a 
managed bean action method is called. In that i do some custom processing and the it
navigates to another xhtml page. Now the problem is that, before moving to next xhtml
page, i need to pass some parameters along with it as well. I have used the following
approaches

1- Put that variable in requestMap and tried to access in the page this way

```
<h:outputText value="#{param['userid']}"/>
```

it doesn't work. Then someone told me there is no standard way in JSF 2.0 to pass 
request parameters along with a URL, so try to pass it as a servlet request. I ammened
the code as follows

```
 ServletRequest request = (ServletRequest)FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequest();
    ServletResponse response = (ServletResponse)FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getResponse();
             //("user",user);
    //ServletRequest request = (ServletRequest)context.getRequest();
    request.setAttribute("userid", "prithvi");
    System.out.println("Came here");
    RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("testf.xhtml");
    try {
        rd.forward(request, response);
    } catch (ServletException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(TestFlashScope.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(TestFlashScope.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
```

I tried to access same way but no luck. no value is displayed. Can someone help me how
to achieve this solution.

BR,
Prithvi

Answer (score 4):

Just set the result as bean property.

`page1.xhtml`

```
<h:commandButton value="Submit" action="#{bean.submit}" />
```

Bean:

```
public String submit() {
    this.result = "blah";
    return "page2"
}
```

`page2.xhtml`

```
<h:outputText value="#{bean.result}" />
```

(assuming that you aren't using `<redirect/>` in `<navigation-case>` if any)

Comment: thanks very much. I still have one confusion that when we press an action button and it navigates it to a new page. Previous request object is lost, it's a new request, so how does the bean still remain in scope means whatever we set in this bean? Additionally, what if we just want to pass a few parameters not the bean, is there something to jsp and servlets we can do in jsf also?

Comment: It's just the same request. JSF is just doing a `RequestDispatcher#forward()`.

Answer (score 1):

you should use Flash Scope. For more information you can look at [this](http://mkblog.exadel.com/2010/07/learning-jsf2-using-flash-scope/) blog post.

Comment: This is only useful when the new page is opened by a **redirect** instead of a forward (which JSF by default uses for naviation).